# Spring Session Ip Whitelist

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, spring-security

I'm trying to find out a way to bind a Spring Security session to one ip. Our current authentication supports IP whitelisting but it's still possible to circumvent this by logging in at a whitelisted network and then changing to a different one.

I've tried using the Session Fixation Prevention method **new session**, by configuring the HttpSecurity with:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .exceptionHandling().and()
            .anonymous().and()
            .securityContext().and()
            .servletApi().and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionFixation().newSession().and()
            ... // URL's access below
```

but this doesn't change anything. I can still login, change my IP using a VPN and do everything without having to attempt to relogin (Which would be blocked because the VPN is not whitelisted)

Is there a way to validate the IP address of a Session on every request using Spring security?

Comment: Your approach is wrong from the start... If your goal is to use a whitelist then use a whitelist... Don't try and attempt to combine (and confuse) that with session creation. Either specify the allowed IP's in all URL's access modifiers. (you can use `hasIpAddress` for that) or add a custom filter in the chain specially for checking the whitelist.

Comment: We do use filter chains and I have attempted to place a validation in one one of our filters, but nothing seemed to stop the chain and bring the user back to login. I might take a look at that again, thank you for your time.

Comment: I was mentioning the spring security filter chain. If you don't have your checks right and always continue processing nothing is obviously going to stop. Just always check the incoming request for the remote IP and it should be in the range, if not throw an exception and let spring security handle that exception.